# Swap Used when there is unused Physical Memory

Tags: macos, memory

I'm running on OSX Yosemite and notice that although there is 7 GB of memory unused, there is still 130 MB of memory used for swap.

Are any apps actually using swap space, which I assume resides on my harddisk? Is this a situation to be concerned with, or is this normal?

I can't figure this out despite reading up on the memory statistics in Mac.

[image]